# Firebird - grant multiple tables

Tags: firebird, firebird2.5

I want to give permissions to a user on all the tables existing in a database. Is there any way to grant a user on multiple tables?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not possible to grant permissions to multiple objects in a single statement, you need to grant per object.